# Solving a Sympy symbolic matrix for an eigenvalue problem returns an empty list

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, determinants

I'm a very new user to Python. I'll appreciate any help you can provide. I'm trying to solve an eigenvalue problem. I have a matrix, which I call 'data3' with elements in terms of an unknown variable 'omega'. The determinant of the matrix will give me the characteristic polynomial in terms of 'omega' from which I can determine the roots or eigenvalues that I need.

The following is my code:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc

omega=sp.Symbol('omega');
data1=sp.Matrix(sc.genfromtxt('./Z_real.csv',dtype=float,delimiter=',')); 
data2=sp.Matrix(sc.genfromtxt('./Z_imag.csv',dtype=float,delimiter=','));
data2a=data2*1j*omega;
data3=sp.Matrix(data1+data2a);

eqn=sp.Eq(sp.det(data3),0);
print(sp.solve(eqn));
```

As seen above, I import data1 and data2 which I then combine to form a complex number matrix (with 'omega' which I need to solve). As an example, my data3 matrix looks like this, when output to the iPython console:

```
Matrix([
[             0.536,  -1.119e-8*I*omega, -1.3558e-8*I*omega, -3.8778e-9*I*omega],
[ -1.119e-8*I*omega,              0.536, -3.8778e-9*I*omega, -1.3558e-8*I*omega],
[-1.3558e-8*I*omega, -3.8778e-9*I*omega,              0.536,  -1.119e-8*I*omega],
[-3.8778e-9*I*omega, -1.3558e-8*I*omega,  -1.119e-8*I*omega,              0.536]])
```

However, the sp.solve(eqn) line of the code returns an empty list for me. What I expect to see are the roots of the matrix polynomial (from the determinant). Can someone please advise me on what I'm doing wrong? Also if anyone can show me alternative ways of solving for 'omega', that would be great too. If you want information on data1 and data2, below are the matrices I use for my test:

data1

```
Matrix([
[0.536,   0.0,   0.0,   0.0],
[  0.0, 0.536,   0.0,   0.0],
[  0.0,   0.0, 0.536,   0.0],
[  0.0,   0.0,   0.0, 0.536]])
```

and data2

```
Matrix([
[       0.0,  -1.119e-8, -1.3558e-8, -3.8778e-9],
[ -1.119e-8,        0.0, -3.8778e-9, -1.3558e-8],
[-1.3558e-8, -3.8778e-9,        0.0,  -1.119e-8],
[-3.8778e-9, -1.3558e-8,  -1.119e-8,        0.0]])
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for anyone who read the post. I have now fixed this issue. Instead of solving the characteristic polynomial of the matrix directly, I found out that it was much easier to get the determinant (now using Berkowitz algorithm - no special reason) in polynomial equation form, extract the coefficients of the polynomial using sympy Poly, then plug the roots inside the numpy roots function. Works like a charm! Please find the code below (the data I import is irrelevant, the method works for any sympy matrix):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import sympy as sp
import csv

omega=sp.Symbol('omega');
data_Za=sp.Matrix(sc.genfromtxt('./Z_matrix.csv',dtype=float,delimiter=','));
L_mata=sp.Matrix(sc.genfromtxt('./L_mat.csv',dtype=float,delimiter=','));
C_mata=sp.Matrix(sc.genfromtxt('./C_mat.csv',dtype=float,delimiter=','));
N_total=int(sc.genfromtxt('./N_total.csv',dtype=float,delimiter=','));

data_Z=data_Za*omega;
L_mat=L_mata*omega;
C_mat=C_mata*(1/omega);

data_matrix=data_Z+L_mat+C_mat;
det_eqn=data_matrix.berkowitz_det();
```

This is how I import the matrices, add them to get the final matrix I want and calculate the determinant - nothing new till here.

```
det_poly_coeff=sp.Poly(det_eqn*(omega**N_total),omega);
#print(det_poly_coeff.coeffs());
```

The matrix that I use is a little complicated because as you can see what I did with C_mat, I will end up with terms in my determinant (the characteristic polynomial) that have the variable `omega` even in the denominator. Sympy's Poly function does not like that. Therefore I end up multiplying the determinant with `omega**N_total` where N_total is the degree of the polynomial equation (and also the highest degree of omega that occurs in the denominator).

```
root_find_sq=np.roots(det_poly_coeff.coeffs());
#print(root_find_sq);
```

Plugging the coefficients into numpy roots gives me the roots of the equation, which are the values that I wanted to solve.

```
root_find=np.sqrt(abs(root_find_sq));
```

Finally the square root because the roots that were solved were for `omega**2` and not directly for `omega`.

Hope anyone else who may have this problem finds this post helpful. Cheers. :)